# Getting ad urls in python

Tags: python, url

Is there a way I can retrieve the ads url from a webpage using python?
For example (http://www.quiltingboard.com/resources/) I want to retrieve the url of the ads on the top as well as the right side. Is that possible?

Comment: Both of them are pretty easy to get at if you download the file, the HTML is contained within the page. The XPath for the image ad at the very least is //*[@id="google_image_div"] according to Chromes analyzer. Take a look at web scraping libraries: http://scrapy.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of pythons html parsers.   My favorite is [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) because it is fast, but it requires external dependencies...

Additionally, if you are looking for ads on any site you will probably need a [list of add domains](http://pgl.yoyo.org/as/serverlist.php?hostformat=adblockplus&showintro=1&startdate%5Bday%5D=&startdate%5Bmonth%5D=&startdate%5Byear%5D=)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use Beautiful Soup (PyPI name `beautifulsoup4`) -- it gives a nice interface for getting what you want out of the page. Docs are [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). It can use several different HTML/XML parsers, from the built-in stuff to `html5lib` or `lxml`.